# how can change the border radius of the the input text filed created by django forms class?

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms, django-templates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="design" style="border-radius:5px; border-color: darkgoldenrod; 
color: aquamarine; ">
<form action="/form/2" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
 <input type="text" style="border-color: darkgoldenrod; border-radius: 
10px;" />
</body>
</html>
```

the text filed  created using the  takes the css command but the textfiled generated using {{form}} is not taking css command.

Comment: Use Django Widget Tweaks. Once installed you can add any css class to the form fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add attributes to your form (including css styling) as

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'myfield': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'border-color:darkgoldenrod; border-radius: 10px;'}),
        }
```

Comment: worked for me, was able to edit the >>
`from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/) just to handle custom css classes for inputs:

```
@register.filter(name='add_class')
def add_class(value, arg):
    return value.as_widget(attrs={'class': arg})
```

And then call like this:

```
{{ form.field|add_class:"foo" }}
```